# How to remove an edge between two vertices from DSE schema

Tags: graph, datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise

We have an edge between two vertices in datastax graph.

How can I remove the edge from the schema itself?

I tried this:

```
schema.edgeLabel("belongswithin").connection("poi", "region").drop()
```

but there is no `drop` method to delete an edge like this.

I can't run:

```
schema.edgeLabel("belongswithin").drop()
```

as I am having the same edge being used between the other two vertices which I don't want to drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DSE Graph, an EdgeLabel can be dropped, but not selectively for a particular connection between two VertexLabels. You don't say which version of DSE you are using, but I'm pretty certain you'll need to drop and rewrite the schema, then load your data again. If you are a DataStax customer, you might want to contact Support to see if there is any assistance they can provide.